# Integrate a two Flutter modules into the same Android project

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build.gradle

I follow [this](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/add-to-app/android/project-setup) documentation to add a flutter module into Android project.

I add this code in settings.gradle

```
/* Flutter embed modules */
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(settingsDir.parentFile, 'libs/flutter_student_embed/include_student_embed.groovy'))
include ':flutter_student_embed'
project(':flutter_student_embed').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '/../libs/flutter_student_embed')


/* aylearn student transport */
setBinding(new Binding([gradle: this]))
evaluate(new File(settingsDir.parentFile, 'apps/aylearn_student_transport/.android/include_flutter.groovy'))
include ':aylearn_student_transport'
project(':aylearn_student_transport').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '/aylearn_student_transport')
```

and I add this in build.gradle

```
/*Flutter embed*/ 
implementation project(path: ':flutter-student-embed')
/* Aylearn Student Transport */
implementation project(path: ':aylearn_student_transport')
```

when I run build, I got this 4 errors

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter-student-embed'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter'.
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
Cause: assert appProject != null
       |          |
       null       false
```

Comment: Does it work with only one Flutter module?

Comment: yes, it work for flutter-student-embed module

Comment: And for aylearn_student_transport? Could you upload minimal sample with this issue to github so I could look?

Comment: I'm sorry, I could not,I found that it not possible right now [link](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39707), the flutter team they working on it.